# Bad access error from within CoreData with sqlite persistent store during RESTKit mapping operation

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a really nasty issue thats causing me to tear my hair out. A bad access error is occurring deep within core data - In terms of visible code I've narrowed it down to a RESTKit one-to-one relationship mapping operation.

I'm using sqlite as the persistent store. This issue does not occur if I use an in-memory etc and only happens on app restart on a non-empty sqlite.

Here is the stack trace from the NSManagedObjectContextQueue:

```
#0  0x03b0380a in semaphore_wait_trap ()
#1  0x03699cde in _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait ()
#2  0x03697516 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow ()
#3  0x03697413 in dispatch_barrier_sync_f ()
#4  0x010562a2 in _perform ()
#5  0x01056ebe in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#6  0x0105f1c4 in -[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] ()
#7  0x0105eb97 in -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willRead] ()
#8  0x0105c204 in -[_NSFaultingMutableSet containsObject:] ()
#9  0x0104ec9e in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _includeObject:intoPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] ()
#10 0x0104eae4 in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] ()
#11 0x0104e332 in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] ()
#12 0x0104df88 in -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] ()
#13 0x02ce48c7 in NSKeyValueNotifyObserver ()
#14 0x02ce6206 in NSKeyValueDidChange ()
#15 0x02ca28dd in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] ()
#16 0x01030825 in _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex ()
#17 0x0102fcad in _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core ()
#18 0x010614a6 in -[NSManagedObject(_PFDynamicAccessorsAndPropertySupport) _setGenericValue:forKey:withIndex:flags:] ()
#19 0x0104fb99 in _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty ()
#20 0x0104fb23 in -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] ()
#21 0x02d2470a in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] ()
#22 0x002e7cc1 in -[RKMappingOperation mapOneToOneRelationshipWithValue:mapping:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingOperation.m:608
#23 0x002eb688 in -[RKMappingOperation applyRelationshipMappings] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingOperation.m:801
#24 0x002ed9d0 in -[RKMappingOperation main] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingOperation.m:899
#25 0x02d6a829 in -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] ()
#26 0x02ce7558 in -[NSOperation start] ()
#27 0x002dc1b5 in -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentation:toObject:atKeyPath:usingMapping:metadata:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:242
#28 0x002db7dc in __63-[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:]_block_invoke at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:214
#29 0x0330c5eb in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#30 0x0330c196 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#31 0x0330c0a5 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] ()
#32 0x002db48c in -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:211
#33 0x002dd410 in -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentationOrRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:299
#34 0x002dde72 in -[RKMapperOperation mapSourceRepresentationWithMappingsDictionary:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:347
#35 0x002de83b in -[RKMapperOperation main] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMapperOperation.m:386
#36 0x02d6a829 in -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] ()
#37 0x02ce7558 in -[NSOperation start] ()
#38 0x003385b7 in __73-[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation performMappingWithObject:error:]_block_invoke at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/Network/RKResponseMapperOperation.m:472
#39 0x01055fef in developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#40 0x036aa4b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#41 0x03697778 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#42 0x03697422 in dispatch_barrier_sync_f ()
#43 0x01055f1f in -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] ()
#44 0x00336da1 in -[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation performMappingWithObject:error:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/Network/RKResponseMapperOperation.m:427
#45 0x00334723 in -[RKResponseMapperOperation main] at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/Pods/RestKit/Code/Network/RKResponseMapperOperation.m:337
#46 0x02d6a829 in -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] ()
#47 0x02ce7558 in -[NSOperation start] ()
#48 0x02d6caf4 in __NSOQSchedule_f ()
#49 0x036aa4b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#50 0x0369807f in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#51 0x03697e7a in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#52 0x03698e1f in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#53 0x03699137 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#54 0x039c2e72 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

And here is the stack trace from the main thread where the bad access occur:

```
#0  0x01005502 in _nameForEntityDescription () // Bad access here
#1  0x010054c7 in -[NSSQLCore entityForFetchRequest:] ()
#2  0x01005595 in -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] ()
#3  0x010604a4 in -[NSSQLCore newFetchedPKsForSourceID:andRelationship:] ()
#4  0x0105f7b6 in -[NSSQLCore newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#5  0x0105f44e in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#6  0x010d4e90 in __107-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#7  0x01056321 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#8  0x036aa4b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#9  0x03697778 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#10 0x03697422 in dispatch_barrier_sync_f ()
#11 0x010562a2 in _perform ()
#12 0x01056ebe in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] ()
#13 0x010d4e90 in __107-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#14 0x01056321 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#15 0x03699440 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke ()
#16 0x036aa4b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#17 0x0369875e in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#18 0x03377a5e in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#19 0x032b86bb in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#20 0x032b7ac3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21 0x032b78db in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22 0x0413b9e2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#23 0x0413b809 in GSEventRun ()
#24 0x01b68d3b in UIApplicationMain ()
#25 0x0002a76d in main at /Users/mtford/Playground/xxx/xxx/xxx/main.m:18
```

I realise I haven't provided much context in terms of mappings+code etc, but does anyone have any ideas based on the symbols involved in the stack trace what the issue may be here?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out i'd accidentally ticked transient on one of my relationships at some point... what a nightmare :)